# How do I decrypt a key encrypted by my HSM under a ZMK?

Tags: encryption, keys, key-exchange, decryption

I've generated a key using an HSM Thales PayShield and i have share it with a counterpart. I followed these steps:

- i generated key usign KG console command
- i use FK to form ZMK from clear components (received by the
  counterpart)
- i exported key key under ZMK (KE command)

Now, in this particular case the counterpart wants the key in clear format and no under ZMK. We are in test environment so we haven't restrictions, but is it technical possible?

> I've the key encrypted LMK and under ZMK, how do I get the key in
> clear?